# AngularJS: http request with missing headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing a request in this way using AngularJS:

```
    var config = { headers: {
            'Authorization': 'somehash',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    } };

    $http.get('http://example.com', config)
        .then(function(response) { 
            $scope.response = response;
    }, function(response) { });
```

The request is fired, but when I check on Firefox (Firebug) the request is missing of the Authorization/Content-Type headers I have set and it returns a "200 OPTIONS REQUEST" that is related to CORS. Anyway I am wondering if the issue is really related to CORS or missing headers and in a case or another what is the solution.

Comment: There must be a GET request sent just after the OPTIONS one: does this request has the provided headers?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you the solution for the cors, but it is server side. you need to write some attribute in the headers. To be precise this ones
Host="the host from you have called the get"
Origin="the origin domain of your request"
Referer="the orgin domain + the page"

and in the request you have to add this
access-control-allow-credentials=true

 and i think it's related to the cors, i had your same problem. If it persist after you had handle the cors, clean the browser cache.